# Electron $(...).selectpicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, electron, bootstrap-select

I need your help. I've been stuck with this problem for 2 days.

I'm building an application with electron (by Atom) and I use bootstrap-select. When I launch the app an error rises even if the function in question has not been called yet:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function
```

Do someone know how to fix that?

Comment: Does the error contain a line number and/or file reference?

Comment: Sounds like you are not including the boostrap-select library...

Comment: @KevinJantzer yes, it's in a function that is not called yet. The library is included because one of the select is shown and correctly works.

Comment: Have you tried doing a global search for `.selectpicker` to see where it appears? And again, no line number appears with the error?

Comment: The line error appears, it points to the following line: $('#' + id).selectpicker('refresh');

Comment: And it's the only time I use it in the whole code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140199/discussion-between-kevin-jantzer-and-ppablo).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. It seems that using

```
require('bootstrap-select');
```

to include the library doesn't work properly, instead, I downloaded the bootstrap-select library and imported manually in the HTML file.

Comment: My select picker is not shown when I launch the electron app. However it is perfectly working on the index.html file. How did you fix your issue? My picker simply doesn't show up when I launch the application